# Query return empty set

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm seeing a strange issue with MySQL query 
I have this table

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| aid          | varchar(50)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sid          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| cid          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| signature    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| sig_name     | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sig_class_id | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sig_priority | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp    | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_src       | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_dst       | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_proto     | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| layer4_sport | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| layer4_dport | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| isp          | varchar(16)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ispdst       | varchar(16)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When i execute

```
 SELECT DISTINCT timestamp
      , aid
      , sig_name
      , inet_ntoa(ip_src)
      , inet_ntoa(ip_dst)
 FROM acid_event
 WHERE ip_src !=0 
   AND ip_dst !=0
   AND 1=1 
   AND aid = '10.10.10.94' 
   AND ip_src = '3305661330'
GROUP BY aid
       , ip_src
       , ip_dst
       , timestamp
       , sig_name
       , isp
ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 0,25;
```

MySQL return results and everything is alright BUT when i change my query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT timestamp
     , aid
     , sig_name
     , inet_ntoa(ip_src)
     , inet_ntoa(ip_dst)
FROM acid_event 
WHERE ip_src !=0 
  AND ip_dst !=0 
  AND 1=1
  AND ip_src = '3305661330' 
GROUP BY aid
       , ip_src
       , ip_dst
       , timestamp
       , sig_name
       , isp 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 0,25;
```

MySQL retun an empty set

Comment: `ip_dst !=0 AND 1=1` What does it mean in your query?

Comment: I use this statement on php to eliminate ip adresse=0 and 1=1 is always true. I have filter table in my php that's why i use 1=1

Comment: Do you have a full text index on aid? If so, check this link: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19661/less-restrictive-query-return-less-result-due-to-simple-removing-one-additional. Take a look at the answer of RolandoMySQLDBA and the links therein. It might help...

Comment: Why do you specify both DISTINCT and GROUP BY? When GROUP BY the result is always distinct. If aggregate functions are involved (SUM, COUNT, MAX etc), use GROUP BY, if you just want duplicate rows removed, use DISTINCT.

Comment: the problem persist when i eliminate distinct and group by ... i think the response of HoneyBadger is useful

Answer (score 1):

In both of the queries you compare an integer with varchar:

```
ip_src = '3305661330'
```

But ip_src is actually an integer(10) unsigned. So try this:

```
ip_src = 3305661330
```

Comment: While true, it wouldn't make sense if this was causing the issue.

Comment: You're right @HoneyBadger but sometimes it makes sense to clean messed up things, since they can cause unexpected behavior.